# Specify arguments when applying function with sapply

Tags: r, function, sapply

I created the following function which finds the columns correlation to the target. The function is applied on the diamonds dataset (assigned to dt here) for this purpose.

```
select_variables_gen <- function(variable, target = dt$price, threshold = 0.9){
  if(all(class(variable) %in% c("numeric","integer"))){
    corr <-  abs(cor(variable, target));
    if(corr > threshold){
      return(T);
    }else{F}
  }else{F}
};
```

Now that I want to apply the function I can't figure out how to specify the arguments of the function. This is what I tried

```
alt_selected_gen <- names(dt)[sapply(dt, 
select_variables(variable = dt, target = dt$carat, threshold = 0.1))]

alt_selected_gen;
```

Which returns an error saying thaht the 2nd and 3rd argument are unused. How can I use the function (with sapply or any other way) to be able to specify the arguments?

My desired output is the column names of the columns which have a correlation above the threshold. So using the default values with the above code that would be;

```
[1] "carat" "price"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass your *function* to `sapply`. What you are trying to pass is a *call* to your function.

When you use `sapply` on a data frame, the columns get sent one by one to your function as its first argument. If you want to pass further named arguments to your function you just add them directly as parameters to `sapply` after the function itself. This works because of the dots operator (`...`) in `sapply`'s formal arguments, which pass any extra parameters into the call to your function.

It should therefore just be

```
names(dt)[sapply(dt, select_variables_gen, target = dt$carat, threshold = 0.1)]
#> [1] "carat" "table" "price" "x"     "y"     "z"
```

Notice also that the function is called `select_variables_gen` in your example, not `select_variables`.

Comment: Correct. The reason is that apply `FUN`functions only accept the one argument they cycle through. Additional arguments cannot be passed directly but as `...` after the `FUN` argument. Look it up with `?sapply`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, appreciate it